# I would like to replace code strings to pre code in text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, syntax-highlighting

I would like to replace code strings to pre code in text.

for example in text:

```
@PHP +++

public function example()
{
    echo "Hello World.";
}

+++

@JS +++

alert("Hello World!");

+++
```

replace to:

```
<pre class="PHP">

public function example()
{
    echo "Hello World.";
}

</pre>

<pre class="JS">

alert("Hello World!");

</pre>
```

my condition now:

```
public function decorate( $str = "" )
{
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8", false);
    $str = str_replace("\t","&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",$str);
    $str = str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$str);
    $str = preg_replace("/@(.+?)\+\+\+(.*)\+\+\+/is", "<pre class='$1'>$2</pre>", $str);
    $str = nl2br($str);

    return $str;
}
```

problem1: The line break duplicate in "pre" from "nl2br" function work.
problem2: The regexp `/@(.+?)\+\+\+(.*)\+\+\+/is` is not correct.

Do you know the correct way?
It is good even if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Per the output of this [live php demo](http://ideone.com/OLkgyc)...**

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(?sm)^@(\S+)[ ]*(\+\+\+)(.*?)\2~',
                         '<pre class="$1">$3</pre>',
                         $yourstring);
```

When you inspect the replacement, make sure to look at it through htmlentities, otherwise the markup won't show. For instance: `echo htmlentities($replaced);`

**Explanation**

- `(?sm)` activates `DOTALL` and multi-line modes, allowing dots to match newlines and `^` to match at line breaks
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `@` matches the literal `@`
- `(\S+)` captures any non-whitespace chars to group 1
- `[ ]*` optionally matches spaces
- `(\+\+\+)` matches three pluses and capture them to Group 2 (so we don't have to type it again)
- `(.*?)` lazily matches and captures to Group 3 all characters up to...
- The `\2` back-reference, which is `+++`
- We replace with `<pre class="$1">$3</pre>`, where `$1` stands for Group 1, and so on.

**Output**

```
<pre class="PHP">

public function example()
{
    echo "Hello World.";
}

</pre>

<pre class="JS">

alert("Hello World!");

</pre>
```

Comment: FYI: fixed a bug, added live PHP demo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
@PHP +++

public function example()
{
    echo "Hello World.";
}

+++

@JS +++

alert("Hello World!");

+++
EOT;
$regex = array('~@(\w+)\s*\+\+\+~','~\+\+\+~');
$replace = array(
  '<pre class="\1">',
  '</pre>'
);
$result = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$string);
echo $result;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<pre class="PHP">

public function example()
{
    echo "Hello World.";
}

</pre>

<pre class="JS">

alert("Hello World!");

</pre>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/chOqM2)

**Explanation:**

- `@(\w+)\s*\+\+\+`  One or more word characters followed by a `@` symbol which has the trailing `+++` are captured. And the corresponding whole line is replaced with `<pre class="\1">`. `\1` represents the 1st group captured.
- `~\+\+\+~` Line which consists of Only three `+++` symbols are replaced by `</pre>`.